# Open 2 Firefox Shortcuts on 2 different screens

Tags: firefox, windows-xp

Is is possible to have 2 Firefox shortcuts on your desktop and when you open them they open to a designated different screen (new window/different screen)?  I have a 3 screen set up, Win XP and using FF3.6.  If no way of coding it, maybe a product that will do it?

I appreciate your time.

Thanks.

Comment: Should probably be on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

On the FF Menu Bar, Tools > Options.

On the "Tabs" tab, deselect "Open new windows in a new tab instead".

Should solve your problem.

Comment: I think he's launching separate instances of firefox and wants them attached to a different monitor.

Comment: Ooooooh.  "a designated different screen".  I read that as "different window".

My bad.

Comment: Jacob, yes i want them attached to different monitors.  I havent seen anything that will do that for me, but it would be really nice.  I do appreciate the info though Douglas, I tried that, but it just opens a new window on the same monitor...

Answer (score 0):

It was an interesting problem; was able to do this using "NirCmd" (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

The commands (in a batch file) are as follows:

```
nircmd.exe exec show "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window [URL_A]
nircmd.exe exec show "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window [URL_B]
nircmd.exe wait [DELAY_FOR_WEB_PAGES_TO_LOAD]
nircmd.exe win move stitle "[FIRST_FEW_CHARACTERS_OF_TITLE_OF_URL_B]" [X_RESOLUTION_MONITOR_1] 0
nircmd.exe win setsize stitle "[FIRST_FEW_CHARACTERS_OF_TITLE_OF_URL_B]" [X_RESOLUTION_MONITOR_1] 0 [X_RESOLUTION_MONITOR_2] [Y_RESOLUTION_MONITOR_2]
exit
```

A simple example:

```
nircmd.exe exec show "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window http://www.google.com
nircmd.exe exec show "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-window http://www.yahoo.com
nircmd.exe wait 2000
nircmd.exe win move stitle "Yahoo" 1280 0
nircmd.exe win setsize stitle "Yahoo" 1280 0 1024 768
exit
```

Please check the "NirCmd" help file for further reference.

Comment: This looks pretty good, rtabarna.  This looks like it may work...I will give it a try and let other know what comes of it. Thanks a lot!